# How to loop through an optional collection

Tags: swift, collections, option-type

What's the *Swifty* way to unwrap an optional collection directly before a loop?
Consider the following:

```swift
let elements: [Element]?
for element in elements { ... }
```

where `elements` may contain values. The compiler produces the error: `For-in loop requires '[Element]?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?`, similarly with `forEach`.

Using the `where`-Keyword to tell the compiler that I only want to iterate if there are values in `elements` like this

```swift
for element in elements where elements != nil { ... }
```

does not work. I am basically looking for a way to unwrap the collection where I don't have to write verbose `guard let` or `if let` before iterating through the loop.

I am not looking to extend `Sequence` with a property that returns unwrapped `self`, I just don't think it's very elegant (including force-unwrapping).

Comment: `for element in elements ?? [] {}` ?

Comment: What is so verbose about `guard` and `if let`? It is the normal way to safely unwrap optionals and to follow a commonly used pattern is an advantage in itself.

Comment: With some styleguides you are required to write 3 new lines of code everywhere you want to unwrap a value, which just _is_ verbose imo. See this [thread](https://forums.swift.org/t/lets-fix-if-let-syntax/48188/17) on the Swift community forums for more opinions on this

Comment: Declaring your collection as constant makes no sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options. You can provide an empty array as the default value for `elements` in a `for ... in` loop:

```
let elements: [Element]?

for element in elements ?? [] {

}
```

Or you can use `forEach` and optional chaining on `elements`

```
elements?.forEach { element in

}
```

Bear in mind that optional collections are an anti-pattern in Swift. You can represent the lack of value using an empty collection, so wrapping a collection in an optional doesn't provide any extra value, while complicating the interface.

Comment: I don't feel like the first option is very nice in regards to readability, I do like the second option, though. I think I was stuck on using `where` so I forgot optional chaining, duh...

Comment: SwiftLint even has a [rule](https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/discouraged_optional_collection.html) for this, nice

Comment: Declaring it as constant makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Your elements are not optional, but array is. In your case just unwrap the array:

```
let elements: [Element]?
for element in elements ?? [] {
    // do stuff
}
```

But if your elements are optional, you can use compactMap:

```
let elements: [Element?] // elements are optional instead of array
for element in elements.compactMap { $0 } {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: if element is nil then you can use it like this ```for case let element in elements {```

Comment: Side note, with the `compactMap()`: You are iterating twice the array... So it might be non-optimized...